# How to store keywords in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My application use keywords extensively, everything is tagged with keywords, so whenever use wants to search data or add data I have to show keywords in auto complete box.

As of now I am storing keywords in another collection as below

```
export interface IKeyword {
    Id:string;
    Name:string;
    CreatedBy:IUserMin;
    CreatedOn:firestore.Timestamp;
 }

export interface IUserMin {
    UserId:string;
    DisplayName:string;
}
export interface IKeywordMin {
    Id:string;
    Name:string;
}
```

My main document holds array of Keywords

```
export interface MainDocument{
   Field1:string;
   Field2:string;
   ........
    other fields
   ........
   Keywords:IKeywordMin[];       
}
```

But problem is auto complete reads data frequently and my document reads quota increases very fast.
Is there a way to implement this without increasing reads for keyword ? Because keyword is not the real data we need to get.

Below is my query to get main documents

```
query = query.where("Keywords", "array-contains-any", keywords)
```

I use below query to get keywords in auto complete text box

```
query = query.orderBy("Name").startAt(searchTerm).endAt(searchTerm+ '\uf8ff').limit(20)
```

this query run many times when user types auto complete search which is causing more document reads

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question

https://fireship.io/lessons/typeahead-autocomplete-with-firestore/

Though the receommended solution is to use 3rd party tool

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

To reduce documents read:

A solution that come to my mind however I'm not sure if it's suitable for your use case is using Firestore caching feature. By default, firestore client will always try to reach the server to get the new changes on your documents and if it cannot reach the server, it will reach to the cached data on the client device. you can take advantage of this feature by using the cache first and reach the server only when you want. For web application, this feature is disabled by default and you can enable it like in

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

to help you understand this feature more check this article:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline

Comment: No this is not I meant, I have certain keywords in collection but keyword search is causing more document reads. let me update my question

Comment: I am using persistence, just wanted to find out is there any other solution for this

Comment: I would say then either exclude the auto complete feature which is increasing the reads or use a 3rd part tool to achieve this functionality like Algolia. There are always tradeoffs and you should decide what fits your need the most.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thought I would share here

Create a new collection named typeaheads in below format

```
export interface ITypeAHead {
    Prefix:string;
    CollectionName:string;
    FieldName:string;
    MatchingValues:ILookupItem[]
}
export interface ILookupItem {
   Key:string;
   Value:string;
}
```

depending on the minimum letters add either 2 or 3 letters to Prefix, and search based on the prefix, collection and field. so most probably you will end up with 2 or 3 document reads for on search.

Hope this helps someone else.